# Why can't I see who all my friend shared a post with?

Tags: google-plus

When a friend shares a post privately on Google+ and I'm one of the ones they shared it with, I can click on the "shared privately" link and it will show me everyone the post was shared with and then at the bottom it says "+2" Why can't I see who those other two people are? Did my friend block me from seeing who all they shared with, or did those people block me from being able to see that they are part of my friend's circles?

Answer (score 2):

> **Shared privately**: The post was shared with specific people or circles. You won't be able to see all of the people who got the post. Only the person who posted can view that information.

[See who you shared a post with](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1283790)